# Laravel Valet Installation Failed

Tags: laravel, valet

I am getting this error while installing valet on my mac machine. Could somebody help?

```
Nginx cannot start; please check your nginx.conf [1: nginx: [emerg] unknown  
   directive "http2_push_preload" in /Users/sujitbista/.config/valet/Nginx/dg  
  demo.test:13                                                                 
  nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed        
  ].
```

Comment: Can you run `brew update`?

Comment: Yep, I can run a brew update. But I have installed MAMP on my machine and I have added PHP path of MAMP in my .bash_profile. Does that caused the problem?

Comment: Take a look here - https://github.com/laravel/valet/pull/573 - I'm not sure why you are experiencing this problem, my guess is because your nginx is old.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have removed the valet directory in .config file and reinstalled it. Then it started working

Answer (score 7):

Remove the valet configurations, reinstall and start.

```
rm -r ~/.config/valet
valet install
valet start
```

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: nginx 1.19.6 is already installed, it's just not linked. To
> link this version, run:

```
  brew link nginx
```

..solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

checking nginx install on your local machine >> which nginx

if not found please install nginx >> brew install nginx

then follow these instructions

rm -r ~/.config/valet
valet install
valet start

Answer (score 0):

Update NGINX

```
    brew upgrade nginx
```